# getBoundingClientRect() is not a function on TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to get all text node by createTreeWalker and check boundary by getBoundingClientRect

However, it produced error message： getBoundingClientRect is not a function

```
// find all text nodes
var treeWalker=document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT);
const nodeList: any[] = [];
let currenNode = treeWalker.currentNode;

while(currenNode){
    nodeList.push(currenNode);
    const node = treeWalker.nextNode();

    if (node == null){
        break;
    }
    else{
        currenNode = node;
    }
}

// check boundary for each text node
for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++){
    let elem: Element = nodeList[i] as Element;

    if(elem != null)
    {
        var container = elem.parentElement;
        if (container != null)
        {
            var e = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
            var c = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    
            if(e.top < c.top || e.left < c.left || e.right > c.right || e.bottom > c.bottom)
            {
                await page.locator('.null.null').click();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is the method document.createTreeWalker(document.body, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT) to get all text nodes correct？

Comment: Looking at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TreeWalker/currentNode, the return type is Node. What happens if you use `nodeList: Node[]` and replace `let elem: ...` with `let elem = nodeList[i];`?

Comment: Thanks @KavianRabbani, I have try to change Node to Element by "let elem = nodeList[i] as Element;" and changed to nodeList: Node[]. But still got the same problem.